# Django Query - Return All objects that have been referenced at least once in a model

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models. Employees and Schedule

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Scheduled(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    assigned_employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to return all employees that have been referenced at least once in Scheduled table.

Note: I have done it with 2 queries, but is there a way to do this in just one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Guillaume for the clue. Although your solution has a slight mistake, but it gave me enough to reach to the exact solution. This query worked for me

`Employee.objects.filter(scheduled__isnull=False)`

**Note**: I am using the default related_name field which is `scheduled_set`.

Comment: I remove the extra _ between scheduled and set. I think you forgot the _set in your own answer. Anyway, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I already checked your solution with single _ but it didn't work with set. It works fine with scheduled__isnull -> (without set, despite of it using the default related name field).

Comment: Alright, this is a weird behavior. You should mark your answer as a correct answer because people might look for similar solution.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

It looks like you should not use `_set` to go through the relationship, the correct answer is:

`Employee.objects.filter(scheduled_set__isnull=False)`

Original:

I have not tried it yet but maybe that should work.

`Employee.objects.filter(scheduled_set__isnull=False)`